# Add Product to cart Same item duplicated

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, php-7

I am trying to add items to my cart in a custom module and have it half working.

The problem is that it adds the same item in place of every other item.

PHP:

```
  $products = json_decode($_POST['products'], true) ?? array();

  foreach($products as $purchase){
    $productId = $purchase['productid'];
    $qty = $purchase['quantity'];
    $params = "";
    $params = array(
                  'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                  'product' => $productId,
                  'qty'   => $qty
              );
      //Load the product based on productID
      $_product = $this->product->load($productId);
      $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
      $this->cart->save();
  }
```

The products variable contains data similar to this:

`[{"productid":"2181","quantity":"1"},{"productid":"2185","quantity":"1"},{"productid":"2189","quantity":"1"},{"productid":"2192","quantity":"1"}]`

If this data was used in the php code, it would add the item with productid 4 times, instead of each item once. I am guessing it is something to do with either the $params array or the $_product variable not being reset at the start of the `foreach`.

How do i make each of the items add correctly with the quantity specified, and also, do i want to be calling this line `$this->cart->save();` inside or outside of the foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found That the problem was within the line

```
$_product = $this->product->load($productId);
```

Magento does not like this being used in a loop for some reason and so the first product was being added in place of every other product in the array.

I fixed the issue by instead using this line:

```
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
```

This successfully loads the new product each time the foreach loops around.